# Does user agent `facebookexternalhit` represent a user click?

Tags: facebook, user-agent, bots, robots.txt

If I see `facebookexternalhit` as a user agent in my logs, should I assume it's a bot or did a Facebook user share my link?

To put it another way, if I paid for ads based on a CPC and only wanted to pay for human-initiated traffic, would this user agent be a positive, negative, or neutral value to me?

Comment: It is Facebook’s scraper reading the Open Graph information from your page. I _can_ be triggered by a user sharing your page, but also for other reasons (f.e. FB updating the info on a link that was shared before). __No__, you can not take that as a sign for human-initiated traffic. It would _at most_ be “neutral”, but calling it “negative” would be closer to reality.

Comment: @CBroe: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Facebook’s scraper reading the Open Graph information from your page. I *can* be triggered by a user sharing your page, but also for other reasons (f.e. FB updating the info on a link that was shared before).

No, you can not take that as a sign for human-initiated traffic. It would at most be “neutral”, but calling it “negative” would be closer to reality.